# Check if all characters are uppercase

Tags: string, rust

I am trying to check if all the characters in a given string is uppercase here but the below code results in `true`. Am I doing something wrong out here?

```rust
fn main() {
    let message =  ":) ?";
    let k:bool = message
            .chars()
            .filter(|x| x.is_alphabetic())
            // .collect();
            .all(|x| x.is_uppercase());
            
    //for val in message.chars() {
    //    println!("{} - {} - {}", val, val.is_uppercase(), val.is_alphabetic());
    //}
    println!("{:?}", k);

}
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a2f9d9cebe026edcd9dc016521c586ab)

Comment: You're filtering them with `is_alphabetic()`.

Comment: but then `all(|x| x.is_uppercase());` should be giving `false`?

Comment: It's true. All alphabetic characters in your message are uppercase. Your message does not contain any alphabetic characters, but all of the nonexistent alphabetic characters are uppercase.

Comment: "All alphabetic characters are uppercase" is logically equivalent to "there are no alphabetic characters that are not uppercase".

Comment: Did you mean to write ` .all(|x| x.is_alphabetic() && x.is_uppercase());`?

Comment: no that is not what I wanted. I wanted to see if all characters which are alphabetic are also uppercase by filtering out characters that are not alphabetic first

Comment: And that's exactly what you implemented. Your code is correct and fits your problem description. Why do you think that the result should be `false`?  `Are all characters which are alphabetic also uppercase` **should** be `yes` for the string `":) ?"`, it's all correct.

Comment: `all` on the empty iterator returns `true`, always.

Comment: [This is even specified explicitly in the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.all).

Answer (score 1):

The code works fine. Since there are no elements in your playground example, it returns true. I don't remember the name for that concept but there's a sort of "trivial truth" in logic to statements like "There are no hats in this room. Therefore, every hat in this room is blue". Since there is no counterexample (a non blue hat), it can't be false. Here's [how the std::iter documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.all) specifies this:
"(...) An empty iterator returns true."

Comment: The term you're thinking of is _[vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth)._

Answer (score 1):

```rust
let message = ":) ?";
let k: bool = message
    .chars()                       // Elements: [':', ')', ' ', '?']
    .filter(|x| x.is_alphabetic()) // Elements: [] (no element is alphabetic, so this is an empty iterator)
    .all(|x| x.is_uppercase());    // true (.all() is always true for empty iterators)
```

It's unclear what you are *attempting* to do, so all we can do is show you why the code behaves the way it behaves.